# Error while freeing an array within a data structure

Tags: data-structures

```
Status bit_flags_set_flag(BIT_FLAGS hBit_flags, int flag_position) {

Bit_Flags* temp = (Bit_Flags*)hBit_flags;
int* nums;
int i;
int old_size;



if (temp->size < flag_position) {
    nums = malloc(sizeof(int)*flag_position+1);
    if (nums == NULL) {

        return FAILURE;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < temp->size; i++) {

        nums[i] = temp->data[i];
    }

    free(temp->data);

    temp->data = nums;

    old_size = temp->size;

    temp->size = flag_position + 1;


    for (i = old_size; i < temp->size; i++) {
        temp->data[i] = 0;
    }

}

temp->data[flag_position / 32] |= 1 << flag_position % 32;

return SUCCESS;
}
```

according to the debugger the error is from the free(temp->data) part. however. I only run into the error the second time I go through the function. any ideas what is happening here.

am getting a heap corruption error on visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing on some assumptions like you are assuming int size is 32 bits and you are trying to set the bit at flag_position in the bitset and you are using 1 int for 1 bit for setting and unsetting bits

Few comments now

temp->data[flag_position / 32] |= 1 << flag_position % 32; now this doesn't make any sense, this line role is to  set bit at flag_position, this should be temp->data[flag_position] = 1; instead because if you see your code your are using ints for each bit.

Also this line temp->size = flag_position + 1; is also incorrect , this should be temp->size = flag_position;

Comment: i might be wrong because i have not seen the whole code and implementation of data structures, so if you can share the code we can see whats the problem exactly.